# Some kind of... code sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What does the following mean? I'm feeling completely dumbfounded.

Is it morse code? Are there anyone on this forum who know what it means? I would really appreciate a "translation". I don't know the complete origin and what kind of code this is. Something about 'Take a prime that's not a prime, what needs to make it ninety nine.' You could take a look at this profile: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui

**_ .... . .. . | . ._. . | __ _ ._. . | _ .... .. _. __. ... | .. . | .... . . ..._ . . | . *. .. | . . .*. _ .... __.. | .... _ .. . _ .. _ .. | _ .... ._ . | . .*. . | .. .. . .* __ _ | _ .._. | .. _. | .. .. | .. .... .. ... ... .. .... _.__ ..._**

Comment: I will do that. But are you really sure that this is morse code?

Comment: I would think his response was to prove it may not be direct morse code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online Morse code translator http://morsecode.scphillips.com/translator.html renders the above as"

THEIE ERE MTRE THINGS IE HEEVEE EEI EEITHZ HTIETITI THAE EIE IIEEMT TF IN II IHISSIHYV

Which seems to be an attempt at Shakespeare:

There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.

I can't explain the difference.

Comment: It seems likely that you're right in what you're saying, the patterns seems to be matching... but now this has turned into a philosophical question.